# Unit test in PyCharm fails if imported a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

With PyCharm, we are trying to create a unit test file `tests/test_poc.py` for a proof-of-concept class `PocFunctional`, and we have added `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=applicationproject.settings` into the "Python tests" section of the "Run/Debug Configurations".

However, if we uncomment `from app.poc import PocFunctional` in the below sample source code to import the class under test, the unit test will get a run-time error saying `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`. Although the file runs OK if not imported the `PocFunctional` class.

We are new to the unit test of Python in PyCharm environment, so we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**Technical Details:**

**Partial unit test source code:**

```py
from unittest import TestCase

# from app.poc import PocFunctional


class TestPocEav(TestCase):
    def test_get_transaction(self):
        # self. Fail()
        return

    # ... other test methods
```

**Exception:**

```
/data/app-py3/venv3.7/bin/python /var/lib/snapd/snap/pycharm-professional/316/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --target test_poc.TestPocFunctional 
Testing started at 5:03 PM ...
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest test_poc.TestPocFunctional in /data/app-py3/APPLICATION/tests

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/snapd/snap/pycharm-professional/316/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 159, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/tests/test_poc.py", line 3, in <module>
    from applicationapp.poc import PocFunctional
  File "/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/applicationapp/poc.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/data/app-py3/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 133, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/data/app-py3/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/data/app-py3/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/data/app-py3/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem likely that your Django application is not totaly loaded.

You should try using `django.setup()` before trying to import the `PocFunctional` class

for example:

```
import django
from unittest import TestCase

class TestPocFunctional(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        django.setup() 
        from app.poc import PocFunctional
        cls.poc = PocFunctional()

    def test_get_transaction(self):
```

do your test transaction in the `test_get_transaction` method it should work